# NSMetadataQuery by folders iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am performing a NSMetadataQuery and I am getting all the URL for both Files and Directories.

```
func initSearchQuery(){
    print("\(logClassName): initSearchQuery")

    searchQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "%K like '*'", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemFSNameKey])
    searchQuery.predicate = searchPredicate

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateDataWithNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: searchQuery)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateDataWithNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object: searchQuery)

    searchQuery.enableUpdates()
    searchQuery.start()

}
```

Is there a way to do a predicate which would give only the URL's for the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I have finally resolved my problem.

Let's assume that we have the path for the iCloud folder

```
var iCloudUrl = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
iCloudUrl = iCloudUrl.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

And now we want to perform a NSMetadataQuery for folder1 inside the iCloud Documents folder.

We could access the content by declaring a NSPredicate like that:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemPathKey,iCloudUrl.appendingPathComponent("Folder1").path])
```

It will return all the URL's for the folder, files and Subfolders.

1) If we just want to get the the files then the NSPredicate will look like that

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@ && NOT %K.pathExtension = ''", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemPathKey,iCloudUrl.appendingPathComponent("Folder1").path,NSMetadataItemFSNameKey])
```

2) If we want to count how many folders and subfolder it has then

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@ && %K.pathExtension = ''", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemPathKey,iCloudUrl.appendingPathComponent("Folder1").path,NSMetadataItemFSNameKey])
```

Comment: Hello, I'm using your solution, but unfortunately the query seems not go through. I want to query the files inside the iCloud Drive folder. Which the path & NSPredicate are:

Comment: guard let containerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") else { return
        }

Comment: query.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemPathKey,containerURL.path])

Comment: I then started the query using:

Comment: _ = self?.query.start()
            self?.query.enableUpdates()

Comment: But I never receive notification from NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate. I'm trying to get update status of 1 file in the iCloud document folder. Is there something I did wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: That's only the predicate.